# Conflict between Interface builder and .m@.h : who win?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode4.2, uitextfield

I've been wondering for a few time now how does Xcode interpret the use of both IB and programmaticaly coded objects.
ex : I initWithStyleGrouped a table in .m but I set plain as the style in the attributes of the tableviewcontroller I am working on. so? I noticed that the code gets over the IB.

It first appears when I had to custom a detail table by insering a header and a UITextField in the first cell which is very easy with IB. But when I run the app, nothing but the template of a plain table.
gnuh??

Thank you for your help.
Cheers,
Louis

**EDIT**

here is the instantiate of the TableViewController :

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They should never cross. If you instantiate a table with [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped], it creates a new table without going though a NIB. If you instantiate a table from a NIB, it creates an instance using -initWithCoder:.

---

**Added after Update**

OK, you are subclassing UITableView. In addition to overriding `-initWithStyle:`, you will want to override `-initWithCoder:` or `-awakeFromNib`.

The basic flow of loading an custom UIView from a NIB.

- `-initWithCoder:` is used to instantiate the object
- All NIB connections are make (IBOutlets and IBAction are connected).
- `-awakeFromNib` is send to the object

This means if you set a value in `-initWithCoder:`, the NIB setting will win;  if you set a value in `-awakeFromNib`, the your code will win.

Be sure to read the Subclassing Notes and Methods to Override sections of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Comment: I don't get it. how works the instantiating process? The conclusion is that I must set it once on either ib or .h@.m ?

Comment: If you create your table view within IB, then you must not call -initWithStyle: for that table view. Post a code sample if you have a specific question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jefferyThomas, I edited the code in my main question.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you initialize the object. If you load the UITableView from your controller's init method and call initWithStyle, that's what your UITableView will be. If you want to use IB's, you'll need to initialize your controller with initWithNibName and have an IBOutlet connection to your view, which has the plain setting.

Comment: Which is what I have :
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

then, I kept designing with IB by introducing a UITextField and a header but nothing appears though I linked the UITextField as an IBOutlet to .h

btw, how to introduce code? it's not so explicit..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure but I think I found a beginning of solution. here are my thoughts.

I consider a IB oriented design.
the compiler will ask for IB to instantiate the view.
But if we created a UITableViewController subclass, then we have all the method refering to the instantiation (correct word?) of this view.

So, in order to avoid this conflict, We can erase the code in the .M which refers to the initialization of the table : initWithStyle and the pragma mark about Table source. we just let the View life cycle needed by any view and the delegate.

I found some exemple using this. here is the .m of a detail view table which is designed with static cells on IB :

```
    #import "PictureListDetail.h"

    @implementation PictureListDetail

    @synthesize managedObjectContext;
    @synthesize currentPicture;
    @synthesize titleField, descriptionField, imageField;
    @synthesize imagePicker;

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
[super viewDidLoad];

// If we are editing an existing picture, then put the details from Core Data into the text fields for displaying
if (currentPicture)
{
    [titleField setText:[currentPicture title]];
    [descriptionField setText:[currentPicture desc]];
    if ([currentPicture smallPicture])
        [imageField setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[currentPicture smallPicture]]];
}
 }

   #pragma mark - Button actions

   - (IBAction)editSaveButtonPressed:(id)sender
    {
// If we are adding a new picture (because we didnt pass one from the table) then create an entry
if (!currentPicture)
    self.currentPicture = (Pictures *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pictures" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// For both new and existing pictures, fill in the details from the form
[self.currentPicture setTitle:[titleField text]];
[self.currentPicture setDesc:[descriptionField text]];

if (imageField.image)
{
    // Resize and save a smaller version for the table
    float resize = 74.0;
    float actualWidth = imageField.image.size.width;
    float actualHeight = imageField.image.size.height;
    float divBy, newWidth, newHeight;
    if (actualWidth > actualHeight) {
        divBy = (actualWidth / resize);
        newWidth = resize;
        newHeight = (actualHeight / divBy);
    } else {
        divBy = (actualHeight / resize);
        newWidth = (actualWidth / divBy);
        newHeight = resize;
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [imageField.image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Save the small image version
    NSData *smallImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallImage, 1.0);
    [self.currentPicture setSmallPicture:smallImageData];
}

//  Commit item to core data
NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    NSLog(@"Failed to add new picture with error: %@", [error domain]);

//  Automatically pop to previous view now we're done adding
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

   //  Pick an image from album
   - (IBAction)imageFromAlbum:(id)sender
   {
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
     }

    //  Take an image with camera
   - (IBAction)imageFromCamera:(id)sender
   {
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
     }

      //  Resign the keyboard after Done is pressed when editing text fields
      - (IBAction)resignKeyboard:(id)sender
     {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
     }



    @end
```

available here : [enter link description here](http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/#more-512)

What do you think ??

Answer (score 0):

Even though I now alone on this post, I wanted to post the answer !

I finally figured out why my textfield didn't appear which show who's has the hand on the compiler.

I actually subclassed the detail with a class wich implement methods to fill the table source with the coreData.Then, the supposed static cells were actually filled with these methods.

Which shows, to my humble opinion, that the .m overpass the IB.